# How to scatter plot with 1 million points

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scatter

I'm trying to make a program that draws a graph using given points from a csv file which contains 4 strings for each row (Number of the point, x pos, y pos, color), but the time it takes is ridiculously high, so i'm looking for ideas to make it faster.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib import style   
import csv

style.use('ggplot')

s = 0.5
with open('total.csv') as f:
  f_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  for row in f_reader:
    plt.scatter(str(row[1]), str(row[2]), color=str(row[3]), s=s)
plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=1000)
```

Comment: If you only need an idea of the trends in the data, subsample the points randomly and only display, say, 1k. Either way, reading in all the data and only calling scatter once (or once per colour if you have specific colours for some points) will be much faster than calling scatter for each point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to call `scatter` once instead of for every points, without adding a dependency on numpy and pandas it could look like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import csv

style.use("ggplot")

s = 0.5
x = []
y = []
c = []
with open("total.csv") as f:
    f_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in f_reader:
        x.append(row[1])
        y.append(row[2])
        c.append(row[3])
plt.scatter(x, y, color=c, s=s)
plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=1000)
```

Then maybe try `pandas.read_csv` which would give you an pandas dataframe allowing you to access the columns of your CSV without a `for` loop, which would probably be faster.

Each time you try a variation, measure the time it take (possibly on a smaller file) to know what help and what don't, in other words, don't try to enhance perfs blindly.

Using pandas it would look like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd

style.use("ggplot")

total = pd.read_csv("total.csv")
plt.scatter(total.x, total.y, color=total.color, s=0.5)
plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=1000)
```

If you want to learn more on pandas good practices for performance, I like the [No more sad pandas](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2017/no-more-sad-pandas-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-and-efficiency.html) talk, take a look at it.